# Return two field values from one SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have following serializer:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    label = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field4 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field5 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = (
            'status', 'label', 'field3', 'field4, 'field5'
        )
```

The problem is, the conditions used to obtain the first two fields are same. So I don't want to run the same codes again in two serializer method fields. I want to get both of the values from the same serializer method.
How can I efficeintly get values of both of the fields from only one serializer method field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [method_name](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) of the SerializerMEthodField.

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_foo')
    label = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_foo')

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('status', 'label')

    def get_foo(self, instance):
        # your code here
```

Comment: Actually I want to run the serializer method one time only and return two values together. I think my purpose won't be served in this way. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return two or more values in one serializermethodfield,

```py
    class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        status = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_foo')
    
        class Meta:
            model = Sample
            fields = ('status',)
    
        def get_foo(self, instance):
            return instance.status, instance.label
```